# How to get datas from array in different component when the page is loading

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some array in component B with some links like this:

```
videoUrlArray = [
    'link1', 'link2',...
  ];
```

Normally I get datas from component to component with ViewChild, it works fine, but there I need datas if I clicked the button. Now I need datas always in component A which come from B.

I came on idea to pass the datas from B component to A over constructor (like in Java e.g.- I'm native Java learning Angular with TS).

So my constructor in B looks like this:

```
  constructor() {
    this.videoUrlArray.push('someExampleLink3');
  }
```

And expected to get datas in A component over:

```
  @Inject(new BComponent()) BObject;
```

I have expected that the method like this:

```
  addCategoryBonStart(): void {
      this.videoUrl.push(this.BObject);
      this.sanitizedVideos = this.videoUrl.map(video => this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(video));
    console.log('BObject' + this.BObject);
  }
```

implemented in ngOnInit will do their job. Instead of this I got Error like this with some iframe which is undefinded and looks bad:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'undefined'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'undefined'
```

Why is it undefined? I'm creating array element with constructor of B object?
How can I get the object on loading of the page?

In html template of A component (where I trie to receive the datas from array in B) is added B template  so it should work.

Comment: https://dev.to/jwp/the-angular-event-service-ech

Comment: https://dev.to/jwp/the-angular-event-service-ech

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your problem I recommend using a shared service which both components import.

Futhermore I recommend the use of BehaviourSubjects. These can be set by a public method of the shared service and subscribed by another component.

Your component A can push elements via the setter method and your component B can subscribe to the BehaviourSubject.

I recommend reading into this topic because its imo a quite powerful concept in angular.